# Custom Validation Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have to do a custom validation in jquery, I have a name textbox and submit button. I have to the validation for unique name. I have array of existing name below is the rule i have created.

```
var  tempArray = ['john','rob','smith'];

$.validator.addMethod('uniqueName', function (value, element) {
    return $.inArray(value, tempArray) > -1;
}, "Name already exists, Please Enter a Unqiue Name.");
```

Below is the form

```
<form id='frmValidate'>
<input type='text' name='username'>
<input type='button' value='submit'>

</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#frmValidate').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        username: {
           required : true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});
```

});

I am not sure how to apply rule to my form. any help would be appreciated. sorry if its a silly question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

```
    var  tempArray = ['john','rob','smith'];

    $.validator.addMethod('uniqueName', function (value, element) {
        return !$.inArray(value, tempArray) > -1;
     }, "Name already exists, Please Enter a Unqiue Name.");


    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#frmValidate').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        username: {
           required : true,
           uniqueName : true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, in your `submitHandler()` you can send an ajax request, with your `username` as a parameter. This ajax request hits a url on server, which can verify whether that username is already taken or not. If it is already taken, show appropriate message, otherwise submit the form.

```
$('#frmValidate').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        username: {
           required : true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted. Now checking for unique username'); // for demo
       var username = $("#username").val();
       $("#pageloader").fadeIn();
       $.ajax({
         url: '/admin/ajax_check_username_availability',
         data: {'username': username},
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(response)}{
            if( response.status == 1 )
            {
              form.submit();
            }
            else
            {
              $("#pageloader").fadeOut();
              alert("'" + username+ "' is already taken. Please try something else.");
            }
         }
    }
});
```